# A word for leaving out a repeated and shared phrase

Tags: word-request

Suppose that you can say

> the black and white ball**s**  == instead of == the black ball and the white ball

OR

> the book and pen == instead of == the book and the pen

Or in mathematics we say

> 3 * (2 + 5)  === instead of 3*2 + 3 *5

What is the name of this action? I mean to just use one word for the shared part. I thought it is **factor out**; however, dictionary says that *factor out* means *to not include something in calculation*. I don't mean a linguistic concept, but just a verb for this action for anything and any situation that it is possible.

Comment: "To omit", possibly. There's also a noun, "**[ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))**".

Comment: @CopperKettle, thanks, but I think "omit" doesn't convey the part is *shared* and also I don't mean a linguistic concept (I modified the question)

Comment: @Adam, thanks, okey, what about "the black and white balls" or "the black and white humans"  or any example you think is better, you name it

Answer (score 1):

- For mathematics , *"factor out"* is most common.

  See [What is the right term to indicate the opposite of the math operation distribution?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46686/what-is-the-right-term-to-indicate-the-opposite-of-the-math-operation-distributi/46687#46687)
- I would not use *factor out* to describe what you did in the book/pen example:

> the book and pen == instead of == the book and the pen

These do not necessarily mean exactly the same thing.  If pen is part of a set with the book (e.g. A diary with a builtin loop to which the pen is attached) it would be more natural to say *hand me the book and pen* rather than *hand me the book and the pen.*

- Suppose we have a non-mathematical example that does preserve meaning:

> Some examples don't preserve meaning, but some do.

This sentence has two examples of ellipsis, in which a word or phrase is omitted and the meaning is implied.

> Some examples don't preserve meaning, but some [examples] do [preserve meaning].

Omission of [examples]  is *noun ellipsis.*
Omission of  [preserve meaning] is *verb phrase ellipsis.*

- I would not use *factor out* to describe what you did in the black/white ball example.

*"The black and white ball"* refers to one ball that has two colors.

*"The black ball and white ball"* refers to two different balls, each of which has one color.

*"The black and white ball**s**",* is ambiguous.  It could refer to either multiple balls, each of is either black OR white, or it could refer to  multiple bi-colored balls.  Without additional context, I would assume it meant the latter (two or more balls, each of which is both black and white.)

Suppose context makes it clear that this is not the case (e.g. a table has three balls on it, each of a different color, and the magician instructs the volunteer to *"pick up the black [balls] and [the] white balls"*).  This is *noun ellipsis.*

You are looking for a "non-technical" synonym for ellipsis.  I can't think of one, probably because this type of analysis of sentence structure rarely happens outside of a "technical" context.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, but please don't take my example as it is, I know there are examples for my intention

Comment: Or for any reason if I do it over two phrases, did I "factor the words out"? I modified my question to correct the first sentence and add another example

Comment: _Factor out_ carries the sense you want _in the realm of mathematics._  I would not use it to describe sentence construction, unless I wanted to sound like I was making a geeky "in-joke."  Maybe there are people somewhere who use "factor out" as a linguistic term in this way, but I haven't met them.

Comment: _I know there are examples for my intention:_  I don't mean to be flip, but I can't think of one that isn't just an example of ellipsis.  As @CopperKettle said in the first place, when parallelism, or other context allows us to leave words out without changing the meaning, we call that _ellipsis._

Comment: If you note I began my question with *suppose that*, then *the black and white balls* is a correct example. I don't care if it is ambiguous when there is no context, but when some black and white balls are in front of me the hearer understand my intention. *ellipsis* is a technical term, I thought maybe there is some simple verbs for some non-mathematical examples! Anyway thank you